# Search documents in one index and get count of rows from another index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have two indices in Elasticsearch, one is the master table and the other table stores the identifier of master table and some other information.

Lets take the below example:

```
Index 1:
id     text
name   text
photo  text

Index 2:
id     text (id from table 1)
user   text
status text
```

A ID from index 1 can have multiple documents in index 2.

Now, i have a search filter that will perform search on index 1. But i also want the total count which is the number of documents of a particular ID in table 2.

So if i want to search documents in table 1 on basis of name and also sort them on basis of count, how can i achieve that? Or should i maintain a separate count field in table 1 that will increment whenever a document is indexed in table 2 or is there any other solution?

This requirement is similar to a JOIN query in MySQL

Comment: I would prefer to keep the count field in table 1 and update it as when needed.

Comment: yes i do feel like doing that and make things easy. but is this approach in line with the Atomicity principle?